# Design Manager Doesn't Appear

Tags: master-page, publishing, site-settings, design-manager

I want to publish my custom masterpage. I clicked Site Settings but Design Manager doesn't appear under menu of "Look and Feel". How can I do appear this option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the site collection level, the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure Feature needs to be active, and on the web level, SharePoint Server Publishing needs to be active.

If not, you are not allowed to change master page.

Answer (score 0):

These features need to be activated to get the Design Manager in SharePoint.

- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (site collection level)
- SharePoint Server Publishing (site level)

Even after activating these two features, if the design manager doesn't appear, just deactivate and re-activate them once again, that will solve the issue.

This [link](http://www.sharepointsurgeon.com/design-manager-missing-sharepoint-online/) describes the steps